# Deriving Mean and Variance of Laplace Distribution

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

It has been a long time since I have used calculus, and I am trying to understand how the mean and variance of the Laplace distribution with pdf
$$f(x|\mu,\sigma) = \dfrac{1}{2 \sigma}\,e^{-\Large\frac{|x-\mu |}\sigma}$$ are derived.

I know that E$[X] = \mu$ and Var$[X] = 2\sigma^2$, but I don't understand how that happens.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your distribution appears to be just the typical Laplace distribution, so I've removed 'generalized' from the title while editing the rest into Mathjax form. There may be generalized Laplace distributions, but this isn't it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $u=x-\mu$, then we have $x=u+\mu$ and $dx=du$. By linearity we have $\operatorname{E}[X]=\operatorname{E}[U+\mu]=\operatorname{E}[U]+\mu$, hence
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X]
&=\frac1{2\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u\  e^{-\Large\frac{|u|}{\sigma}}\ du+\mu\\
&=\frac1{2\sigma}\color{blue}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\int_{-\infty}^0 u\  e^{\Large\frac{u}{\sigma}}\ du}}_{\color{red}{\text{set}\ u=-u}}}+\frac1{2\sigma}\int_{0}^\infty u\  e^{-\Large\frac{u}{\sigma}}\ du+\mu\\
&=-\frac1{2\sigma}\int_{0}^\infty u\  e^{-\Large\frac{u}{\sigma}}\ du+\frac1{2\sigma}\int_{0}^\infty u\  e^{-\Large\frac{u}{\sigma}}\ du+\mu\\
&=\large\color{blue}{\mu}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}\left[X^2\right]&=\operatorname{E}\left[(U+\mu)^2\right]\\
&=\operatorname{E}\left[U^2\right]+2\mu\operatorname{E}\left[U\right]+\mu^2\\
&=\operatorname{E}\left[U^2\right]+2\mu\operatorname{E}\left[X-\mu\right]+\mu^2\\
&=\frac1{2\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u^2  e^{-\Large\frac{|u|}{\sigma}}\ du+\mu^2\\
&=\frac1{2\sigma}\color{blue}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\int_{-\infty}^0 u^2  e^{\Large\frac{u}{\sigma}}\ du}}_{\color{red}{\text{set}\ u=-u}}}+\frac1{2\sigma}\int_{0}^\infty u^2  e^{-\Large\frac{u}{\sigma}}\ du+\mu^2\\
&=\frac1{2\sigma}\int_{0}^\infty u^2  e^{-\Large\frac{u}{\sigma}}\ du+\frac1{2\sigma}\int_{0}^\infty u^2  e^{-\Large\frac{u}{\sigma}}\ du+\mu^2\\
&=\frac1{\sigma}\color{blue}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\int_{0}^\infty u^2  e^{-\Large\frac{u}{\sigma}}\ du}}_{\color{red}{\text{set}\ v=\frac{u}{\sigma}}}}+\mu^2\\
&=\sigma^2\int_{0}^\infty v^2  e^{-v}\ dv+\mu^2\\
&=2\sigma^2+\mu^2,
\end{align}
where
$$
\Gamma(n+1)=\int_{0}^\infty v^{n}  e^{-v}\ dv=n!\qquad,\qquad\text{for $n$ natural number}.
$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[X]&=\operatorname{E}\left[X^2\right]-\left(\operatorname{E}[X]\right)^2=\large\color{blue}{2\sigma^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go through it step by step. I need to get better at recognizing when to substitute.

Comment: @NonNormal You're welcome.

Comment: how can you set u to -u?

Comment: Are you sure thet the line before $2 \sigma^2 + \mu^2$ is correct? I think $u=(v \sigma)^2=v^2 \sigma^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Standardizing the distribution will make the calculations much simpler.  Let $Y = (X - \mu)/\sigma$; then the PDF of $Y$ is $$f_Y(y) = f_X(\mu + \sigma y) \left| \frac{d}{dy}[\mu + \sigma y]\right| = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|y|}.$$  Hence $$\mathrm{E}[X] = \mathrm{E}[\mu + \sigma Y] = \mu + \sigma\mathrm{E}[Y].$$  But note that $$\int_{y=0}^\infty ye^{-y} \, dy = \Gamma(2) < \infty,$$ and $y f_Y(y)$ is an odd function, hence $\mathrm{E}[Y] = 0$ and $\mathrm{E}[X] = \mu$.

Similarly, the variance is best obtained through $Y$: it is a simple matter to compute the second moment of $Y$, since the integrand is an even function:  $$\mathrm{E}[Y^2] = \frac{1}{2} \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty y^2 e^{-|y|} \, dy = \int_{y=0}^\infty y^2 e^{-y} \, dy = \Gamma(3) = 2.$$  Consequently, $$\mathrm{Var}[X] = \mathrm{E}[(X - \mu)^2] = \sigma^2 \mathrm{E}[Y^2] = 2\sigma^2.$$

Comment: It's interesting how many different ways there are to go about this. I certainly appreciate this approach. Hopefully I'll get the mechanics down soon to think this way.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the support of a Laplace Distributed random variable $X$  is the real line, so we have to evaluate the following integral:

$$E\left[X \right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_X(x) \mathrm{dx}= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \dfrac{1}{2 \sigma}\,e^{-|x-\mu |/\sigma} \mathrm{dx}$$

I think that it is the absolute value that is confusing you here, yes?

The solution would be to split it into (disjoint) parts where the sign changes, that is get rid of the absolute value and evaluate them separately:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \dfrac{1}{2 \sigma}\,e^{-|x-\mu |/\sigma} \mathrm{dx}= \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \frac{x}{2 \sigma}e^\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\mathrm{dx}+\int_{\mu}^{\infty} \frac{x}{2 \sigma} e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}}\mathrm{dx}$$

You can now proceed by employing integration by parts on each integral. This should give you the mean.

For the variance you also need to use the same method and evaluate $E[X^2]$. You may then use the variance formula: $var(X)=E[X^2]-\left[ E[X] \right]^2$ to obtain your other result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense. I've been trying to brush up on my integration, but I kept running into issues and getting wonky answers. Thanks!